# how can you merge arrays systematically without losing data?

Tags: php, arrays

so I'm trying to write a method that will merge all the arrays with a certain key value, but the problem I'm running into is that when I try and unset the array, so that there are not duplicate results it skips over several things, which is confusing me. so any advice on how I can improve this method would be greatly appreciated. the other question I have.. is there a way to check if each of these arrays have all 4 keys that I'm looking for.

'Release Date' =>
'Spreadsheet and Flyer Month' =>
'Advertise in Monthly Update' =>
'Feature in Catalog' =>

so what I'm doing is merging arrays with the same id in the db, so I don't have to do some really nasty SQL querys, but I'm wondering if there's a way of making sure that all 4 of these keys will be in every result... and if there is a value associated with one or however many.. my method will add the value to its key, and if there is no value associated with the key it will just make a empty string.

```
protected function array_with_same_val($array, $key) {

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        for($j = 1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
            if(isset($array[$j]) && isset($array[$i]) && $array[$i][$key]==$array[$j][$key]) {
                $temp = array_merge($array[$i], $array[$j]);
                $array[$i] = $temp; 
                //unset($array[$j]);    
            } 
        }
    }   

    return $array;
}
```

Here is a sample of my array (there will be a lot more values, this is just to give an idea):

```
    '0' => array
    (
        'Release Date' => 'September 1, 2013',
        'cp_id' => '112960' 
    ),

    '1' => array
    (
         'Spreadsheet and Flyer Month' => 'September 1, 2013',
         'cp_id' => '112960' 
    ),

    '2' => array
    (
         'Advertise in Monthly Update' => 'September 1, 2013',
         'cp_id' => '112960' 
    ),

    '3' => array
    (
       'Release Date' => 'September 1, 2013',
         'cp_id' =>  '109141' 
    ),
    );
```

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there only one array? Could you provide a sample of your array(s)?

Comment: just added an example

Comment: _"If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."_

Comment: So, probably `foreach($array[$j] as $key=>$val) $array[$i][$key] = $val;`

Comment: Do you want to merge those that have the same 'cp_id'?

Comment: @SomeSillyName yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ($input is the array you provided above) ...

```
$output = array();
$requiredKeys = array('Release Date' => '', 'Spreadsheet and Flyer Month' => '', 'Advertise in Monthly Update' => '', 'Feature in Catalog' => '');

foreach ($input as $item) {
    if (array_key_exists($item['cp_id'], $output)) {
        $output[$item['cp_id']] = array_merge($output[$item['cp_id']], $item);
    } else {
        $output[$item['cp_id']] = array_merge($requiredKeys, $item);
    }
}

$output = array_values($output);
```

The array_values call at the bottom is just to remove the string keys from the array.

Comment: You are my hero... thank you so much! it works great perfect!